# \nocite{*} and \printbibliography not working

Tags: biblatex, citing, overleaf, apacite

I'm using this [template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/msc-dissertation-template-the-university-of-manchester-eee/wxtvdqdhnpwp) however, in my work, the \nocite{} and \printbibliography functions do not work. Below are the package loadings in the preamble.

```
\usepackage{graphicx,psfrag,color} 
  \graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage{amsmath}               
  \allowdisplaybreaks[1]           
\usepackage{amssymb}               
\usepackage{url}                   
\usepackage{rotating}              
\usepackage{multirow}              
\usepackage{lscape}                
\usepackage{tabularx}              
\usepackage{verbatim}              
\usepackage{footnote}              
\usepackage{float}                
\usepackage{booktabs}              
\usepackage{lipsum}                
\usepackage{subcaption}            
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{underscore}

\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=biber,backref=true,hyperref=auto]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references}
\bibliography{references.bib}
```

And here is the code for the referen.ces section where things are called

```
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
```

[Here is the link to the full document](https://www.overleaf.com/read/sgmmkbybkbvv) if you're interested. Feel free to make a copy. I've tried following the overleaf page on [references](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_in_LaTeX) but it doesn't work either.

Comment: `\addbibresource` expects the full name of the file, so `\addbibresource{references.bib}`.  And you should also remove `\bibliography{references.bib}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. also the line `\bibliography{references.bib}` does not require

Comment: You have multiple errors unrelated to the bibliography/citations and `biblatex` (at least four). You cannot expect a functioning bibliography/citations if your document errors. You must fix these errors before you continue. Apart from that gusbrs comment is very relevant. You should have only `\addbibresource{references.bib}`.

Comment: Click on the little icon with the red number next to the "Recompile" button to see all errors and warnings in your document. Address all errors. Start with the first (errors can have knock-on effects, so later errors may resolve themselves if you fix earlier ones). Look at all warnings and decide whether you need to do anything about them. If you need help, ask a new question that reproduces the error message with as little code as possible: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864.